# How to use comments in csv table to get a text classification?

Tags: python, csv, nltk

I have several statements if people like a product or not I have anonymized the comments, and used other names.

As the classification problem is very similar to those of movie reviews, I relied totally on the tutorial from http://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html. Section 1.3.

```
 from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews
 documents = [(list(movie_reviews.words(fileid)), category)
             for category in movie_reviews.categories()
             for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids(category)]
 random.shuffle(documents)

all_words = nltk.FreqDist(w.lower() for w in movie_reviews.words())

word_features = list(all_words)[:2000] [1]

def document_features(document): [2]
    document_words = set(document) [3]
    features = {}
    for word in word_features:
        features['contains({})'.format(word)] = (word in document_words)
    return features

featuresets = [(document_features(d), c) for (d,c) in documents]
train_set, test_set = featuresets[100:], featuresets[:100]
classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)
```

So far so good.

My concern is that my data are organized in following way.

```
sex;statement;income_dollar_year
"m";"I REALLY like milk. It taste soo good and is healthy. Everyone should drink it";40000
"f";"Milk itself is tasty, but I don't like how cows are kept in huge stables";30000
"m";"I don't like milk, I have intolerance against lactose, so my stomach pains";35000
```

I just want to have labels that say that statement one and two are positive and third one is negative. I also know that I have to remove all words that are not in the dataset, otherwise  I would have Zeros and that would make me into trouble.

As I do not have an idea about how the data in movies_review are exactly organized, I don't come to a solution.

my idea is to get a csv like this:

```
sex;statement;income_dollar_year;class
"m";"I REALLY like milk. It taste soo good and is healthy. Everyone should drink it";40000;"pos"
"f";"Milk itself is tasty, but I don't like how cows are kept in huge stables";30000;"pos"
"m";"I don't like milk, I have intolerance against lactose, so my stomach pains";35000;"neg"
```

Comment: So you want to somehow automatically label your training data so that you can train a classifier to predict the label?

Comment: right. From the trained model, I want to use the statements from my csv in, and a csv with the labels 'pos' and 'neg' should be assigned to the statement.

Comment: I don't think you really understand how this works. You need to start with labeled training data to build a model. If you already had a way to automatically label your data, then why would you need to build a classifier? Nevertheless, one thing you can look up is sentiment analysis from `nltk` - they should have some modules that will characterize text as positive or negative.

Comment: I think (but I might be wrong) that you are expecting a bit too much from the classifier, I believe that the movie database had comments and somewhere a numeric value like stars that say if the comment is good or bad.  This way the classifier was able to "learn" good comments and bad comments from stars and then you could give the classifier a new comment (without stars) and it would understand if it is good or bad. In you model you are basically expecting the classifier to understand english right away.. not sure that it is possible.

Comment: I used these three lines as an example that express my idea about an outcome. The problem is how to use a specific statement to plug it into the classifier to get the outcome. The model based on the movie_review data is the trained model. The data from my questionnaire are new and unseen data. As they are organized in totally different way as the data in movie_review, I am asking how to make both compatible with each other.

Comment: If you are asking how to predict new values with an existing model, you can use `classifier.predict()` but you have to make sure that the data is in the same format as what was used to train the model.

Comment: As I cannot take a  closer look on movies_review, what kind of formatting is expected? In the tutorial they just load them in and made the training and test dataset